# sorting different types of objects

Tags: c#

I have 3 types of objects with same baseclass. What is the best way to make an array of object with same base class?
Do I have to create generic type and use Comparer to do this or there is a way to use some arraylist class instead?

I need to sort object by types AND by fields.
Like this: coupe1,coupe2,sedan1, sedan2,sedan3,hatchback1 etc. and by fields of all array elements.

```
class Program
{
    abstract class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Maxspeed { get; set; }                      
        public override string ToString() { return Name + " | " + Maxspeed.ToString();}
    }
    class Coupe : Car
    {
        public Coupe(string name, int maxspeed){ Name = name; Maxspeed = maxspeed;}
    }
    class Sedan : Car
    {
        public Sedan(string name, int maxspeed) { Name = name; Maxspeed = maxspeed;}
    }
    class Hatchback : Car
    {
        public Hatchback(string name, int maxspeed){  Name = name; Maxspeed = maxspeed;}
    }
    class Cars<T>:IComparer<T> where T:Car
    {
        private T[] cars;
        private int length;
        public int Length
        {
            get{ return length;}

        }
        public Cars(int i)
        {
            if (i > 0){ cars = new T[i]; length = i;}\
        }
        public T this[int i]
        {
            get {return cars[i];}
            set{cars[i] = value;}
        }



        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Coupe coupe1 = new Coupe("Audi R8", 250);
        Sedan sedan1 = new Sedan("Suzuki Ciaz", 180);
        Hatchback hatchback1 = new Hatchback("Hyundai Elantra", 170);
        Cars<Car> cars = new Cars<Car>(3);
        cars[0] = coupe1;
        cars[1] = sedan1;
        cars[2] = hatchback1;
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(cars[i].Name + " " + cars[i].Maxspeed.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"What is the best way to make an array of object with same base class?"_ - Make an array of base class (`Car[]`).

Comment: Your concrete classes add nothing to the base class. You may as well just call them all a `Car`

Comment: Why do you need to create all that child classes? Just create some `enum CarType` and property `public CarType CarType { get; set; }` and use that.

Comment: each class will have different method

Comment: @Rdd Sure, I assumed that would be the case. But you realise once you put them in a list of `Car` you wont know which is which, and therefore wont be able to call these specific methods. Inheritance hierarchies are not always the best way to solve problems... in fact they rarely are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just had a `List<Car>` you can use LINQ `OrderBy` to order them first by their type then by anything else

```
Coupe coupe1 = new Coupe("Audi R8", 250);
Sedan sedan1 = new Sedan("Suzuki Ciaz", 180);
Hatchback hatchback1 = new Hatchback("Hyundai Elantra", 170);
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(3);
cars.Add(coupe1);
cars.Add(sedan1);
cars.Add(hatchback1);
var orderedByTypeThenSpeedDescending = cars.OrderBy(x => x.GetType())
                                           .ThenByDescending(x => x.MaxSpeed);
```